# gsub within before_validation method is zeroing out my value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I'm trying to remove dollar signs and commas from my form input (for example, $1,000.00 => 1000.00)

I have the following following line in my before_validation method in my model:

```
self.parents_mortgage = self.parents_mortgage.to_s.gsub!('$,','').to_i
```

This is causing any number to be put through to zero out. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tr`:

```
self.parents_mortgage = self.parents_mortgage.to_s.tr!('$,','').to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.parents_mortgage = self.parents_mortgage.to_s.gsub!('$','').gsub!(',','').to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

self.parents_mortgage = self.parents_mortgage.to_s.gsub('/[\$,]/','').to_i

Because yes there was a problem with your syntax.  Your regex needs the / wrapping, it needs to indicate that $ and , are a character group (by surrounding with []) and you need to escape the $